# Color cell offset of cell contain date conditional formatting

Tags: conditional-statements, formatting

Im looking for a conditional formatting formula that color a cell 2 rows down of a cell with a date (when its 2 months before that date). the date cell do color already within 2 and 1 month to today.
What i like that the cell containing "No" turn green if more than 2 months in the future.

The matrix run from January till December from E6:Q80 [Maintenance matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d4zMa.jpg)

I searched everywhere but i cannot find a solution using conditional formatting. for this sheet i do not like to use VBA.